# Port forwarding raspberry pi port 80 without router access

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, portforwarding

Is there any way to port forward port 80 to my internal Pi ip address without going into router settings? Since I live on campus i don't really think that it is an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port forwarding should be done by the router.

If you cannot access the router configuration and you are on a private network then there is no way to access it from outside except if your raspberry py contact the client in first place.

You might ask a person in charge of the router to do it for you I guess.

It could bring security issues if any devices in the network could have access to port forwarding...

Answer (score 1):

If your router supports [uPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), you may be able to create a port mapping that way.  But that kind of thing is unlikely to work on a properly managed network.  Especially not for well-known ports!

Answer (score 1):

UPNP is the only way to do it without accessing the router. You can use a tool like UPNP PortMapper do do this but It will probably not wok on campus wifi.